# Apache Velocity performance pitfalls?

Tags: velocity, performance

We are using Apache Velocity for website templates and some of them are getting complex. Have you noticed any performance issues with certain Velocity features? And how did you get around them?

Comment: If you have doubts, then profile it. With a profiler. No need to guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important feature people often overlook is resource loader caching (off by default) which boosts performance quite a bit (`file.resource.loader.cache`).

`#parse` directive also has noticeable performance impact, try to use it only to avoid code duplication, not to just split templates into logical parts.

If your templates becoming quite complex in terms of logic maybe it would be possible to shift that logic to a controller and provide a template with ready to render data structure.

I didn't notice any performance drops from Velocity, when I was testing Velocity speed before switching from JSP they were constantly 50% faster on any template I threw at them. Currently we generate sites with thousands of pages rendered from Velocity templates and it is lightning fast, very satisfied with performance.

Comment: Moving calls to Java code that produce the same value each time outside of loops may improve performance as well.  This seemed to help in my situation.  Java's Hotspot compiler does this for Java code - I'm not sure if this feature exists in the Velocity engine.

Answer (score 13):

First of all use the latest velocity library(1.7 or 1.6.4).
Version 1.5 contains some serious performance issues!

Also here is the list of parameters that you must tweak on **production** environment:

1. **velocimacro.library.autoreload** - should be set to **false**
2. **file.resource.loader.cache** - should be set to **true**
3. **file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval** - should be set to **-1**
4. **parser.pool.size** should be increased if default value is not big enough(default value is 20)

Answer (score 2):

We try to cache the `byte[]` in the `ASTText` node to avoid encoding the output text too much times.

Comment: Can you exlain more details how you did it?

Comment: I think I have known how you did it.Thanks~! But why you say it  will encoding the output text too much times. I don't understand it.

Comment: @Clark Well, I'm not from taobao.com. There're two method in `HttpResponse`: `getWriter` to get a `PrintWriter` and `getOutputStream` to get an `OutputStream`, and if you call `PrintWriter.write()`, the servlet container will convert the `char[]` or `string` you write to `byte[]` using the specific encoding. So, if your template is full of static texts, ther is no need to convert `char[]` to `byte[]` every time you send a request to a URL.

Comment: But what if in template there is some dynamic things?

Comment: @Clark Well, you should modified all the node that produce texts( Whether static or dynamic) to support write `byte[]` to the `writer`.